# How to make a map black and white?

Tags: views, google-maps

I created a view (using [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views)) which shows node locations in a map using [Location](https://www.drupal.org/project/location) and [Gmap](https://www.drupal.org/project/gmap) modules.

How can I make map black and white?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `class` name for node locations field, for example "`nodeLocation`"

and in `style.css`

```
.nodeLocation{
      -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
      filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```